# Why does Airflow reschedule tasks that did not exist at the time when clearing other tasks

Tags: airflow

When clearing a task of a DAG for January and Februrary 2019, I noticed that all tasks of this DAG that did not exist at the time were triggered.

- I'm wondering why this happens. I suppose the scheduler is kind of "forced" to look at the DAG runs of January and February, and because the tasks that did not exist at the time never ran for these execution dates, they get triggered. But I'd like to put concrete words on this vague understanding of the situation.
- Can I avoid this? This creates unexpected behavior and has me doubting before launching a big replay of a month that is long past :)

Answer (score 0):

We have also encountered this problem and I think it makes sense. As per Airflow documentation stated.

> Once you clear a DAG, it will be cleared as if it never runs.
>   so in my understanding, it will check all dag and task instance all over again, run all the task until it reached the schedule time.

- *Can I avoid this?* I'm no airflow expert but I think as of now, we can't. What we normally do is to duplicate the DAG we want to rerun and set **start_date** and **end_date**, so it will not intervene with the current DAG that is running normally.